# iPhone ASIHTTPRequest supports https?

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

Does the iPhone librarby ASIHTTPRequest supports https protocol?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

According to the comments for `initWithURL`:

> // Should be an HTTP or HTTPS url, may
>   include username and password if
>   appropriate

So, yes, it should support HTTPS. Although I have not tried it.

Answer (score 3):

HTTPS is supported.  I've been using these classes for HTTPS rather extensively lately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes actually, In that case you have to send password and username as shown in the below example.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
```

More information on the ASIHTTPRequest is found in the following URL :

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

EDIT : You can also try :

```
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]
```

Which works for self signed certificates.